# Getting sum() of an attribute in loopback without looping through all instances of the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a model `DummyModel` that has the attributes `attOne`, `attTwo` and `attThree`.

To get all the instances of `attOne`, one can use-

```
DummyModel.find({where: {attTwo: 'someValue'}, fields: {attOne: true} });
```

The above query corresponds more or less to the `MySQL` query -

```
select attOne from DummyModel where attTwo = 'someValue'
```

However, I need to find the sum of all the attOne values returned from the above query. That is, the MySQL equivalent of -

```
select sum(attOne) from DummyModel where attTwo = 'someValue'
```

I read that loopback doesn't support aggregrate functions (i.e. `groupby`). But is there any way to get`sum(attOne)`?

I know one way is to get the object and then loop over all the instances and add it.

What I want to know is if there's any pre-existing loopback method to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that this code

```
f = DummyModel.find({where: {attTwo: 'someValue'}, fields: {attOne: true} });
```

returns an array like this

```
[
{attTwo: 'someValue' ,attOne: 1}
{attTwo: 'otherValue',attOne: 1}
]
```

you can use the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to apply a function to all elements

```
var sum = f.reduce(function(last, d) {return d.attOne + last},0);
```

And here is the working code

```js
DummyModel = {
  find: function(a) {
    return [{
      attTwo: 'someValue',
      attOne: 1
    }, {
      attTwo: 'otherValue',
      attOne: 2
    }];
  }
}

f = DummyModel.find({
  where: {
    attTwo: 'someValue'
  },
  fields: {
    attOne: true
  }
});

sum = f.reduce(function(last, d) {
  return d.attOne + last;
}, 0);

alert(sum);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. One small query, though. Does this have any performance benefits over using a `for` loop, or is it the same?

Comment: Essentially is the same but in a more concise and [functional style](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html) using the [mapreduce philosophy](http://stevekrenzel.com/finding-friends-with-mapreduce). This can lead to better paralelization in some arquitectures. http://jcla1.com/blog/javascript-mapreduce/